# translate3d causing longer recalculate style phases than positioning with top/left?

Tags: css, performance, rendering, gpu, translate3d

I'm trying to dive deep into browser rendering and came up with this little demo in preparation for a talk.

I put together a animation demo where you can easily switch scheduling from `requestAnimationFrame` to `setInterval` and also positioning from `top/left`-based to `top/left`-based in combination with `translate3d(0,0,0)` or even entirely `translate3d(x,y,z)`-based.

Now I know that s`translate3d` isn't a silver bullet and especially that it can become costly if applied to too many elements. However, there is one particular thing that caught my attention. If I switch the `positioner` from `DefaultPositioner` to `Translate3dPositioner` it seems that I get much longer Recalculate Style phases than before. I couldn't find any information about that so I'm wondering if anyone can share more info about what's going on here?

Here is the link to the demo: http://plnkr.co/edit/TKwKBk?p=preview

Just switch implementations inside the `app.js` file.

One more thing: When you click on resume to kick off the demo, you should wait a little bit until all boxes moved a bit apart. I know it's a poor demo ;-)